# How to restrict particular user roles from Adding child pages to the particular books only.

Tags: users, nodes

I am using drupal 7. I want to restrict some users from adding book pages to the books.

I have several books on my site and each book has different authors. As i have given add book 
pages access to authors any author can add book pages to any book which i dont want.

I just needed to give add book pages access to each author bookwise.
Is there any module available for this i am already using book access for editing the content but i didnt find for adding content restriction.

Answer (score 0):

All [node access modules](https://drupal.org/node/270000), including [Book access](https://drupal.org/project/book_access), are whitelist only.

> Node access modules always GRANT access and never restrict it. (It is a whitelisting rather than a blacklisting system.) If you use two node access modules and one grants access while another does not, access is granted. Exceptions are the [Deny access](http://drupal.org/project/deny_access) module, as well as the old [Module Grants](http://drupal.org/project/module_grants) module through which it is possible to combine access grants across multiple modules in a more intuitive way. Without it, the displayed behaviour may appear backwards from what most people would assume, and it's the reason why it is tricky to get involved with multiple node access modules. It is possible to use multiple node access modules in harmony however if for example they are applied to different content types or are giving out different grant types.

This means **you need to deny access to books, generally, and then use  [Book access](https://drupal.org/project/book_access) to grant it per book.** If you grant it via Drupal settings, you will grant it to all books, and grants are additive - so some people would be allowed, and some would be "doubly allowed", and no one will be denied.

Comment: But my question is how to deny those authors from adding the pages where they don't have add page access.

Comment: @AkshaySawant so if you deny it globally and only allow in Book Access, it does not work?

Comment: See i have defined separate role for the new book and then i created that new book.
So by default this new role should not have access to add child pages to older book this is my understanding.
In general i have given add book pages permission to this new role as well as in book access permission i have given add child pages permission.
so where i am doing wrong?
If i am denying the add book pages permission and only giving from book access then its not showing at all the Add Child page option.